# Undefined при обращении к Ajax об'єкту

Tags: jquery, html5

Пытаюсь сделать простой конвертер валют!Курс валют беру с сайта https://fixer.io через Api

```js
//Load value
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key={!KEY!}',   
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            for(let key in json.rates){
                $('.changeLoad').append('<option>'+key+'</option>')
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="change" class="changeLoad" id="changeValuteFrom"> </select>
```

В селект подгружаю из айпи валюты!
Дальше пытаюсь по клику взять value и получить значния валюты но в итоге получаю undefined!

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key={!KEY!}',   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        for(let key in json.rates){
            $('.changeLoad').append('<option>'+key+'</option>')
        }
    }
});

$('#js-exchange-start').click(function(){

        let changeValuteFrom = $('#changeValuteFrom').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key={!KEY!}',   
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(json) {
                console.log(json.rates);
                console.log(json.rates.RUB);
                console.log(json.rates.changeValuteFrom); //undefined
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="change" class="changeLoad" id="changeValuteFrom"> </select>

<button class="btn" id="js-exchange-start"><i class="fas fa-dice-d20"></i> Обменять</button>
```

Comment: Значит такого объекта нет, покажите Response который возвращает сервер.

Comment: Так дело в том что если я напишу вручную json.rates.ВАЛЮТА , то в итоге я получаю нужное значения.  console.log(json.rates.RUB) - получу значения 75......
А если я беру тоже значения из бокса console.log(json.rates.changeValuteFrom) - получу ундефайн

Comment: Потому что так: `json.rates[changeValuteFrom]`

Comment: Если изменить на json.rates[changeValuteFrom] тот же undefine

Comment: Значит `changeValuteFrom` содержит имя ключа которого нет в `json.rates`
Покажите вывод вот такого кода: `console.log('1)'+json.rates.[changeValuteFrom]);console.log('2)'+changeValuteFrom);`